# Is there a way to check the contents of an Amazon Lex V2 event object that is being passed to a lambda function in AWS?

Tags: debugging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lex

Is there a way to check the contents of an Amazon Lex V2 event object that is being passed to a lambda function in AWS?

To further elaborate, I received this error message while testing a chatbot that uses a lambda function for validation.

[image: Error from testing chatbot in Lex]

Next, I went to the Cloudwatch logs for the lambda function to view the log which had this error.
[image: Error from lambda function's Cloudwatch log]

Here is the pertinent line from my code.

```
if(event.currentIntent.slots.city_str){
```

My objective is to figure out the details of the **event** object being passed to the validation lambda function so I can correctly access the parameters and build validation logic for the Lex chatbot.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Found answer on repost.aws.  See https://repost.aws/questions/QUYrNbTSBsTTyZylyXRyrz0A/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-contents-of-an-amazon-lex-v2-event-object-that-is-being-passed-to-a-lambda-function-in-aws